# How to unregister gcm in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I used GCM to send notifications to user browsers. To register GCM service I used

```
function registerCallback(registrationId) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // When the registration fails, handle the error and retry the
    // registration later.
    return;
  }

  // Send the registration token to your application server.
  sendRegistrationId(function(succeed) {
    // Once the registration token is received by your server,
    // set the flag such that register will not be invoked
    // next time when the app starts up.
    if (succeed)
      chrome.storage.local.set({registered: true});
  });
}

function sendRegistrationId(callback) {
  // Send the registration token to your application server
  // in a secure way.
}

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.local.get("registered", function(result) {
    // If already registered, bail out.
    if (result["registered"])
      return;

    // Up to 100 senders are allowed.
    var senderIds = ["Your-Sender-ID"];
    chrome.gcm.register(senderIds, registerCallback);
  });
});
```

My Extension is getting connection with GCM and I am sending notifications to user browsers. My Question is How to unregister GCM token when user uninstall extension. There is no uninstall event in chrome extension. Could you please any one tell me where to write unregister GCM Connection code in my chrome extension.

Where to write this code in my extension (background.js, contentscript.js)..

```
function unregisterCallback() {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // When the unregistration fails, handle the error and retry
    // the unregistration later.
    return;
  }
}

chrome.gcm.unregister(unregisterCallback);
```

Comment: there is setUninstallUrl which might help you do it from an external server. now, why you need unregistering if the notification won't reach the user anyway?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I installed my chrome extension and uninstalled so many times to test my extension in my PC each and every installation one GCM id is creating (10 times I am installing means 10 GCM ids are created). Whenever I was sending a notification to users I was getting 10 notifications because of my GCM ids are not un registered. I don't know where to call unregister function my extension.

Comment: @Java4you I'm dealing with the exact same issue :) Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be automatically unregistered from the GCM service when the user uninstalls it. No need to have an event listener for it!

source - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client

Comment: Your app or extension could call gcm.unregister to revoke the registration token. The unregistration should only be done in rare cases, such as if your app or extension does not want to receive further messages, or the registration token is suspected to be compromised.